# is there an adjective could describe a very strong belief which is going to be a crazy

Tags: verbs, adjectives

how can I describe that i am stick to an emotion, and gradually go into the crazy way. For example, when I broke up with my significant other, I know I should calm down myself, but I still contact them thought I could change the situation. Or I did something out of the pathway, I notice it, but still keep doing and think things gonna change somehow.

Comment: Are you looking for a medical term, or a casual word?     What adjective would you use in your native language?  Does the dictionary translate it usefully?

Comment: Parts of your question are hard to understand:  "I did something out of the pathway" is not an English idiom.  Nor is "I am stick to an emotion" I can understand that, but the question isn't really about being stuck in one emotional state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are focused on something beyond reason, because of some emotional reaction or attachment to it, you would say that you are [**obsessed**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsessed) with it:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> *adjective*
>   : preoccupied with or haunted by some idea, interest, etc. : being in a state of obsession
>
> // Gatsby the *obsessed* lover, erecting an empire and stringing it with lights to impress a girl …
>   — Claudia Roth Pierpont
>
> // But it seems we're becoming so *obsessed* with healthy eating, we are embarking on up to three different diets a year.
>   — Unity Blott
>
> [obsession](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsession)
>   *noun*
>   **1** : a persistent disturbing preoccupation with an often unreasonable idea or feeling
>   *broadly* : compelling motivation
>       // an *obsession* with profits
>       // has an *obsession* with gambling
>   **2** : something that causes an obsession
>       // Losing weight can be an *obsession* that results in the avoidance of certain foods.

Generally speaking, when somebody is *obsessed* it indicates an unhealthy state that can lead to negative consequences if not put in check.

Although it is possible to be obsessed with something in the short term, and have it motivate you to accomplish something, it's often the case that when the word is used to describe someone it indicates worry about their behaviour.

In terms of the question itself, you could say something like this:

> After I broke up with my significant other, I became increasingly *obsessed* with the thought of them. I was unable to calm down, and I continued to contact them—even though though I knew my behaviour was inappropriate, and that it was unlikely to change anything.